# Combining all elements of multiple large sequences

Tags: r

I try to "combine" multiple sequenzes like 'large numeric' or 'large char' to a single 'large numeric' or 'large char' sequence while keeping the duplicates of the combined object elements and not changing the order of elements.

union() does almost what i want

```
      x <- c(0,1,6,2,3,4,5)


      y <- c(6,0,0,1,3,0,4,5,1,3,-1)


      z <- union(x,y)

      z

      #results in
      #[1]  0  1  6  2  3  4  5 -1


      #but what i need is:
      #[1] 0 1 6 2 3 4 5  6  0  0  1  3  0  4  5  1  3 -1
```

Since  x and y become huge (up to millions of values) a loop attempt might fail due to computation time.

In R there are a lot of functions to combine all kinds of data; therefore hours of search yielded not what i needed, but the solution can´t be so hard to find (frustration)

Comment: use `c` i.e. `c(x, y)`  `union` returns the unique elements

Comment: You finished my hours of search with 4 letters... works perfectly fine.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use concatenate

```
c(x, y)
```